# Wiring entities loaded via repository

Tags: spring

Inside my entities managed by spring data I need some services that should be autowired by spring.

```
public class MyEntity {
  @Autowired
  private SomeService service;

  @Id
  private String id;

  ...
}
```

Is it possible to tell spring to autowire the given service when loading that entity?

I know I could do something like this:

```
public class Worker {
  @Autowired
  private AutowireCapableBeanFactory autowireBeanFactory;

  @Autowired
  private MyEntityRepository repo;

  public void doSomething() {
    MyEntity entity = repo.findOne("1");
    autowireBeanFactory.autowireBean(entity);
    entity.useService();
  }
}
```

Can I automate that autowiring?

Comment: It is no good design. Entities are abstraction of persistence object. This should not use any services.

Comment: Why? Why must I implement service over service to do things an entity could do on its own?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I had to overwrite the `MappingMongoConverter`. How that can be done is described under [Set MongoDb converter programatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13780692/set-mongodb-converter-programatically)