# Setup custom converters in Spring Data Mongo

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb, mongodb-java

We are trying to setup our own Converters for `Spring Data Mongo` and having problems with it.

Seems like Spring never calls for `registerConvertersIn` on CustomConversions and thus our custom converters added through overriden `AbstractMongoConfiguration#customConversions` never become part of conversion.

We are using Spring Data Mongo 1.6.3, but it seems it could be a problem for 1.8.0 too (I've checked calls to `CustomConversions#registerConvertersIn` and found none.)

I was able to fix this problem by calling `CustomConversions#registerConvertersIn` in custom `MappingMongoConverter` like this:

```
class MongoConfig extends AbstractMongoConfiguration {
    @Bean
    @Override
    public MappingMongoConverter mappingMongoConverter() throws Exception {
        DbRefResolver dbRefResolver = new DefaultDbRefResolver(mongoDbFactory());
        MappingMongoConverter converter = new MappingMongoConverter(dbRefResolver, mongoMappingContext()) {
            @Override
            public void setCustomConversions(CustomConversions conversions) {
                super.setCustomConversions(conversions);
                conversions.registerConvertersIn(conversionService);
            }

        };
        converter.setCustomConversions(customConversions());
        return converter;
    }
}
```

Is that a bug or we are doing something wrong?

Found another work around:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/14369998/4567261

Comment: Seems like better way to call afterPropertiesSet on MappingMongoConverter. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13780692/set-mongodb-converter-programatically Still unclear why it could not be done automatically by Spring Data Mongo itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you annotate your `MongoConfig` class with `@Configuration` ?

Your class MongoConfig need to be managed by the Spring BeanFactory to get callback `afterPropertiesSet()`( where `conversions.registerConvertersIn(conversionService)` is originally called ) automatically called

If you don't annotate you configuration bean you need to call `afterPropertiesSet()` yourself

Answer (score 28):

In Spring Boot 2.x it's as simple as creating a registration bean that registers all of your converters:

```
@Configuration
public class Converters {

  @Bean
  public MongoCustomConversions mongoCustomConversions() {

    return new MongoCustomConversions(
        Arrays.asList(
            new MyClassToBytesConverter(),
            new BytesToMyClassConverter()));
  }
}
```

Then create your converter classes:

```
@WritingConverter
public class MyClassToBytesConverter implements Converter<MyClass, Binary> {

  @Override
  public Binary convert(MyClasssource) {
  // your code
  }
}
```

```
@ReadingConverter
public class BytesToMyClassConverter implements Converter<Binary, MyClass> {

  @Override
  public MyClass convert(Binary source) {
  /// your code
  }
}
```

Comment: there are 5 different converter classes (bson, jackson-databing, spring-core etc..), Could you mention which one have you used in your your converter classes please?

Answer (score 14):

Nothing worked for me but this.

While setting up `mongoTemplate` we need to tell to mongo db use the custom conversion:

```
@Bean
public MongoTemplate mongoTemplate() throws Exception {
    MongoTemplate mongoTemplate = new MongoTemplate(mongo(), mongoDatabase);
    MappingMongoConverter conv = (MappingMongoConverter) mongoTemplate.getConverter();
    // tell mongodb to use the custom converters
    conv.setCustomConversions(customConversions()); 
    conv.afterPropertiesSet();
    return mongoTemplate;
}
```

Follow this link for more details:

- http://ufasoli.blogspot.in/2017/06/custom-converter-for-mongodb-and-spring.html

Comment: Worked for me, please consider providing the code for the 'customConversions' Method. Mine looks like this:
@Bean
    public MongoCustomConversions customConversions() {
        List<Converter<?, ?>> converterList = new ArrayList<Converter<?, ?>>();
        converterList.add(new ObjectIdToIdConverter());
        converterList.add(new IdToObjectIdConverter());
        return new MongoCustomConversions(converterList);
    }

Answer (score 11):

It took me one hour to figure out in the **LATEST VERSION** of spring data mongo, `org.bson.Document` should be used instead of `com.mongodb.BasicDBObject`. Here is an example:

```
@Component
@WritingConverter
public class UserModelConverter implements Converter<UserModel, Document> {

    @Override
    public Document convert(UserModel s) {
        Document obj = new Document();
        obj.put("firstName", "FirstName");
        obj.put("lastName", "LastName");

        obj.remove("_class");

        return obj;
    }
}
```

Comment: i spent more than an hour before finding your post. thanks for this. i don't understand why this isn't published more widely and why BasicDBObject is not backwards-compatible with a deprecated warning. Very poor upgrade experience.

Comment: Agreed. Wasted so much time until I found this answer, every guide I found uses BasicDBObject.

Comment: I love you so much right now! Wasted a couple of hours of pointless trying before finding your solution. Annoyingly, the spring-data.mogodb docs actually use String, instead of Document!? :mindblown: