# Getting Failed to instantiate [java.nio.HeapByteBuffer]: No default constructor found while retrieving from Mongo

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, reflection, spring-data-mongodb

I have a java class as follows

```
@Data
@Document(collection="sample_collection")
public class sampleClass {
  private Instant createTime;
  private Object payLoad;
  // some more fields
}
```

The payload object can be null or object of different classes, and can contain a field of type byteBuffer.

Now, while trying to save this to Mongo as a document, I get no issues, but which retrieving the document, I get the instantiationException( whenever the payload object is populated and has the byteBuffer field )

Below are the exception details:

```
org.springframework.data.mapping.model.MappingInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate java.nio.HeapByteBuffer using constructor NO_CONSTRUCTOR with arguments 
at org.springframework.data.convert.ReflectionEntityInstantiator.createInstance
at org.springframework.data.convert.ClassGeneratingEntityInstantiator.createInstance
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read
```

I'm unable to find a way to define a constructor for the HeapByteBuffer field.
Any leads would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

From my point of view you should use more concrete class as field in your entity
OR
you can try to use Converters as workaround of this issue:
[Setup custom converters in Spring Data Mongo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34212545/setup-custom-converters-in-spring-data-mongo)